# kactivities-stats demo only displayed documents without applications

Tags: kde-plasma

Does kactivities-stats collect application running information?

I compiled the test code,found that only displayed documents without applications
I think there might be something that needs to be configured
I checked the kactivitymanagerd database and there was no application information

source code here: https://github.com/KDE/kactivities-stats/tree/master/tests
thanks for your help!